# For a finite set A of positive integers, prove that the set A + A - A contains more positive than negative elements.

Tags: combinatorics

I am working on a project that would need to use the following theorem that I cannot prove.

"Let $A$ be a finite set of positive integers. Then, the set $A + A - A$ contains more or equally as many positive elements than negative elements. ($0$ is counted as a positive element)"

To clarify: The set $A + A - A$ is defined as $\{a_1 + a_2 - a_3|a_1, a_2, a_3 \in A \}$

For example: If $A = \{2,5\}$. Then $A+A-A = \{-1, 2, 5, 8\}$

The nature of this problem lies in the duplicants that can occur. It is intuitively clear, that the theorem should be true since we add an element of A two times but subtract an element only one time. However, it seems to me that it is very hard to prove.

Here is the idea I have been working on so far (which might be the wrong way to go about this):

Let $A = \{a_1, a_2,...,a_n\}$. We first look at the set $A-A$. This set is symmetric around zero. For every element $x$ in $A-A$, $-x$ also occurs in $A-A$. This means that for every negative element, there also exists a unique positive element.

Next we look at the set $a_1 + A - A$. This just shifts $A-A$ to the right. Some negative elements might change into positive ones, but we do not care about that. What is important is, that every positive element stays positive. Therefore again, this set contains more or equally as many positive than negative elements.

Now it gets tricky. My next idea is to look at the set $a_2 + A - A$ and take the union with the set $a_1 + A - A$. I want to do this with every $a_i$. That means in the end I take the following union: $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i + A - A$ which is exactly $ A+A-A$.

I want to prove at each step that there are still more or equal positive than negative elements in the current set. My idea to do this is to think of the following: Since $A-A$ was symmetric around $0$, I can split $A-A$ into elements that are $>0$ and elements that are $<0$ (we do not care about the $0$). These two subsets have the same size. If we add an $a_i$ to a positive element, we have two cases:

1. case: We get a new element that does not already occur in our union of sets.
   In this case we do not have to do anything.
2. case: We get a duplicant. In this case we need to show that we also get a unique duplicant if we add $a_i$ to a certain negative element.

I do not want to go into too much detail, but I was very close to find a method for the 2. case. It always gave me a negative duplicant, but was not unique in very few specific cases.

If somebody has an idea for this problem, maybe even with a complete other method, I would be very grateful to hear and also very excited to discuss it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @legionwhale I think OP expresses most of what you're thinking of in the writeup. Their concern is when the positive numbers overlap between $a_1 + A - A$ and $a_2 + A - A$ (because we're counting unique values), and could theoretically result in a smaller total than the negative numbers.

Comment: @legionwhale I didn't get that for the following reasons:  1/ Not quite clear to me why you only consider the case $x_1, x_2 \geq 0$. What happens with $x_1 > 0, x_2 < 0$? 2/ Why is $a_1 - x_2 < 0 $? If it is positive, then this could lead to the "overlap resulting in smaller total".

Comment: Note: I believe that simply counting overlaps isn't enough, because there is likely more non-negative overlaps (But I might be wrong). The saving grace is that we also have more non-negative numbers to start off with.

Comment: @legionwhale This was exactly my method! However, with this method it is possible that two different positive overlaps refer to the same negative overlap. This happens just in a very special case.

Comment: I will try to think of an example.

Comment: @CalvinLin $x_1, x_2 \ge 0$ actually doesn't make a difference, so I shouldn't have added it. But for $a - x > 0$ (where WLOG $x>0$), it seems to me this case can be disregarded (even if it is an overlap) because we do not have any issue with getting a non-negative number. To MathwithFrank, yes, I agree, that case does make it tricky. It seems to me that the idea can be made to work, but I concede it is not clear without a clever way to count. I'll delete my previous comments since you are already aware of the idea.

Comment: Example: Let's say A-A contains {4,5,7}
Let's say a1 = 6, a2 = 8 and the newest addition is a3 = 5
Then 4+6 = 10 and 5+5 = 10, also 4+8 = 12 and 7+5 = 12.
Both of these overlaps refer to the same negative overlap -4 +5 =1

Does that make sense?

Comment: @MathwithFrank I understand what you mean about the special case from the work I have done. However, I was trying to use induction on arbitrary symmetric sets $X$ (which can then be built up to $A-A$) rather than trying to use induction on $A$. In particular, I believe the statement would hold true for $A+X$ with $X$ arbitrary symmetric. I won't write any more since I don't have time to think about this further. Good luck with solving this.

Comment: @legionwhale. I agree that this more general statement should be true. 
Btw I also think that this case from before can be disregarded.

Comment: @legionwhale That's ok. Thank you for all your input!

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447403/for-a-finite-set-a-of-positive-reals-prove-that-the-set-a-a-a-contains-at-l

Comment: A counterexample has been mosted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/a/447486/116247

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

I have been shown incorrect over on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447403/for-a-finite-set-a-of-positive-reals-prove-that-the-set-a-a-a-contains-at-l/447486#447486), but hey the counterexample comes from Terry Tao so I don't feel too bad about not finding it.

---

This ended up being much, much longer than I expected to get to at least mostly rigorous, so apologies in advance for a long answer. The short answer is yes: creation of overlaps is "coupled" between negative and positive elements, in such a way that the number of negative elements is always smaller than the number of positive elements.

---

(I) Let's start by making $A$ an ordered set, with $0 < a_1 < a_2 \cdots < a_n$, and labeling sets of size $n$ as $A_n$ in general. We will denote $B = A+A-A$ and $C=A-A$ as well, with $B_n, C_n$ used as appropriate.

There are three fundamentally different ways to make a member of $B_n$, giving three subsets. We have:

$$
\begin{align}
B_{n, 1} & = \{a_j + (a_i - a_j) = a_i \mid a_i, a_j \in A_n\} = A \\
B_{n, 2} &= \{a_i + a_j - a_k \mid a_i, a_j, a_k \in A_n\} \\
B_{n, 3} &= \{2a_i - a_j \mid a_i, a_j \in A_n\} 
\end{align}
$$

Let's consider the maximum possible cardinality $B^*_n$ of $\lvert \{B\} \rvert$. We can see there are: $n$ possible elements in $B_{n, 1}$; $(n-2)\binom{n}{2}$ possible elements in $B_{n, 2}$; and $2\binom{n}{2}$ possible elements in $B_{n, 3}$. The sum of these, $B^*_n = n\binom{n}{2}+n$, happens to be [OEIS A006000](https://oeis.org/A006000), with $B^*_2 = 4, B^*_3 = 12, B^*_4 = 28, B^*_5 = 55, \cdots$.

---

(II) Now let's look at the maximum number of *negative* elements of $B$, *assuming* we also have the maximum number of elements. It's clear that all elements of $B_{n, 1}=A$ are positive. To maximize the negative elements in $B_{n, 2}$, we want to have $a_m > a_{m-1} + a_{m-2}$ for all elements of $A$. Then every triple where $k>j>i$ gives an element $a_i+a_j-a_k < 0$, and we will have $\binom{n-1}{2} + \binom{n-2}{2} + \cdots + \binom{2}{2} = \binom{n}{3}$ negative elements in $B_{n,2}$. If we choose our set such that $a_m > 2a_{m-1}$, then exactly half of the elements in $B_{n,3}$ are negative. Hence there are a maximum of $\binom{n}{3} + \binom{n}{2} = \binom{n+1}{3}$ negative elements in $B_n$ for $n\ge 2$. As $n$ gets large, the ratio between this and the total number of elements approaches $\frac13$, with a maximum of $\frac{35}{96} < 0.365$ at $n=5$. **(*)** This becomes important later.

(Note that set $B$ has *no* negative elements if $2a_1 > a_n$. Proof left as an exercise, etc.)

---

(III) OK, but what happens when we shrink $B$? If we choose $A$ such that $B$ does *not* have the maximum number of elements, does such shrinkage allow the negative elements to overtake the positive elements? The answer is "no," but we have a few more steps. For the moment, assume our starting point has the maximum cardinality of $B$, and the maximum number of negative elements in $B$.

First, let's look at *subsets* of $A$, specifically triples $(a_x, a_y, a_z)$. Each triple gives $12$ elements of $B$, as shown above; call this subset in general $B_{xyz}$. Clearly there are $\binom{n}{2}$ triples in $A_n$; just as clearly, there is overlap among the various $B_{xyz}$ for $n>3$, as $12 \binom{n}{3} > n\binom{n}{2}+n$ for $n>3$.

If we change one element of $A$, say $a_i$, such that some subset $B_{ijk}$ shrinks due to new overlaps, then some subsets, like $B_{pqr}$, will be left unchanged. Others, like $B_{ij \ell}$, *may or may not* change in cardinality. Since we're starting from sets of maximal size, $\lvert B_{ij \ell} \rvert$ will, at least, not increase.

There are exactly two changes we can make that decrease $\lvert B_{ijk} \rvert$:

- (i) Change $a_i$ such that three of the differences in $C$ are in arithmetic progression. That is, in the altered set, $2a_j - 2a_i = a_k - a_j$
- (ii) Change $a_i$ such that three of the elements of $A$ are in arithmetic progression. In the altered set, $a_j - a_i = a_k - a_j$. Note that this choice causes $\lvert C \rvert$ to decrease (by $2$).

Finally, if a change in $a_i$ also decreases $\lvert B_{ij \ell} \rvert$, it means $B_{ij \ell}$ will change in one of the above manners as well. That is, any changes we make to alter the original (maximal) set $A$ can only change the cardinality of $B$ in these two ways.

---

(IV) Let's look at the elements of $B_{ijk}$, assuming $4a_i < 2a_j < a_k$ to get the maximum number of negative elements:

$$
\begin{align}
B_{ijk} = &\{a_i, a_j, a_k\} \\
&\cup \{\color{red}{a_i+a_j-a_k}, a_j+a_k-a_i, a_k+a_i-a_j\} \\
&\cup \{\color{red}{2a_i-a_j, 2a_i-a_k, 2a_j-a_k}, 2a_j-a_i, 2a_k-a_i, 2a_k-a_j\}
\end{align}
$$

Highlighted in red are the four elements that are negative under our assumptions.

If we alter $a_i$ as in choice (i) above, so that $2a_j - 2a_i = a_k - a_j$, we find that this creates two new duplicates:

\begin{align}
\color{red}{2a_i - a_j} &= \color{red}{2a_j - a_k} \\
2a_j - a_i &= a_i + a_k - a_j \\
\end{align}

And here, ***finally***, we have the "coupling" of overlaps. This change causes two negative elements to overlap, and two positive elements to overlap. This means that we still have more positive elements than negative elements in $B$.

Now what about choice (ii)? We alter $a_i$ such that $a_j - a_i = a_k - a_j$. That gives us a large number of new overlaps:

\begin{align}
\color{red}{2a_i - a_j} &= \color{red}{a_i + a_j - a_k} \\
2a_k - a_j &= a_j + a_k - a_i \\
2a_j - a_i &= a_k \\
a_i + a_k - a_j &= a_j \\
\color{red}{2a_j - a_k} &= a_i
\end{align}

The first equality decreases the number of negative elements by $1$. The next three decrease the number of positive elements by $3$. And that last equality... well, that last equality does what? Well, we know $a_i$ must remain positive, so this overlap removes a negative element. This change, then, couples a decrease of three positive elements with a decrease of two negative elements. That might be an issue...

---

(V) Except, wait... what's this? Why it's the **(*)** that I said back in Part II would be important later, coming to the rescue! Hello again, **(*)**! What's that you say?

Aha! Of our maximal set, we know from **(*)** that *at most* $36.5\%$ of the elements are negative, and so *at least* $63.5\%$ are positive. Dividing those, this means positive and negative elements are in *at least* a $1.74:1$ ratio.

Using choice (i), we remove positive and negative elements in a $1:1$ ratio. Using choice (ii), we remove them in a $1.5:1$ ratio. No matter how many alterations we make as outlined in Part III, we remove *comparatively more* of the negative elements as we go. If we start with a $1.74:1$ ratio, and make an alteration, the ratio will always *increase*, until eventually we (1) run out of alterations we can make, or (2) run out of negative elements, leaving only positive elements behind.

Hence, at all times, the subset of positive elements of $B$ is greater than the subset of negative elements of $B$, as desired.

We made it! Time for <s>a drink</s> <s>a break</s> bed, really? How time flies. Good night, and I hope this actually withstands testing. Please point out holes/mistakes, of course.

---

EDIT: Responding to the question below regarding how the steps in III and IV work together. Here's a better explanation that I'm more convinced of. I'm certain it could be made more rigorous by somewhat who's spent more time on set theory than I have.

As you say, we want to prove the statement for set $A_n$, and we'll start with some other set $A'_n$, where $\lvert B' \rvert = B^*_n$ as defined above. To complete the proof, we change elements of $A'_n$ one at a time, over time converting $B'_n$ to $B^{(1)}_{n}, B^{(2)}_{n}, \cdots$ until at some point, $B^{(k)}_{n} =B$. When we change $a'_i$, all elements of $B$ that included $a'_i$ in their calculation also change. Those are all the subsets $B'_{i[yz]}$ for all $y,z$ used as indices.

Set $B'$ has maximal cardinality and the maximal number of negative elements (I suppose this number could use a symbol, call it $B^{*-}_n$, I'll likely edit that in above). When we change $a_i$ to create $B^{(1)}_{n}$, we consider each subset $B_{i[yz]}$.

Each triple subset may change its cardinality; the first time around, each one can only either decrease or remain the same. If its cardinality *does* change, then either (i) one positive and one negative element are removed, or (ii) three positive and two negative elements are removed. This may happen for several triple subsets, but in each case we've seen that the only way to change the triple subset (from maximal) is in these two ways.

After we've changed one element of $A'$ and found $B^{(1)}_{n}$, another change can cause an *increase* in cardinality in one or more of the triple subsets. That increase can happen in one of two ways, the reverse of the decreases: the subset gains one positive and one negative element, or it gains three positive and two negative elements.

There is one other unconsidered possibility. It's possible to have a change in the number of negative and positive elements *without* changing the total cardinality. But since we started from $B^{*-}_n$ negative elements, in the first change, this can only replace negative elements with positive ones. In subsequent changes, this can be reversed, gaining  negative elements and losing positive ones. But the backwards step can only happen as many times as we've already had forward steps. We can never go past that initial maximal number of negative elements for each triple.

So in conclusion, we can have any of these transitions go forward or backward--but they can't go backward more than they've come forward. We can't run out of positive elements to remove before we run out of negative elements to remove.

Of note, something I missed for larger sets: It's possible to have an arithmetic sequence as a subset of $C$, yet have $B$ at maximal cardinality. This appears to happen when the arithmetic sequence is formed from three different pairs of $a_i, a_j$, in which case the sequence does not fit the equations given, or when some $a_j = 2a_i$, which loses maximal cardinality of negative elements (as $0$ is considered "positive" in $B$). This, however, changes nothing about the remainder of the proof--it's merely something to notice as an aside.

---

Finally, this sequence:

$$a_i = 1, 3, 8, 19, 43, 93, 200, 418, 864, 1766, 3575, 7196, 14449, 28956, 57972, 116006$$

Is the smallest one I've found that fits the criteria: Take the first $n$ items on this list as the elements of $A_n$. The set $A_n$ will produce a set $B_n$ with maximal cardinality and maximal cardinality of negative elements.

Comment: Hi Eric! Thank you for your hard work, that is really impressive. I still have to re-read the proof later today to be 100% convinced, but it looks very good to me so far.

Comment: So, I looked at it again and have a few questions. If I understand correctly, the idea is the following:
We want to prove for a set A. We start with a set A' of same size that produces the maximum number of elements and negative elements. We then change each $a_i$ in A' until we transformed A' into A and prove that these alterations do not bother us.
However, at step (IV) we assume that the set $B_{ijk}$ contains the maximum number of negative elements. Once we make an alteration we cannot assume this for the next alterations I think. Wouldn't that create a problem or am I missing something?

Comment: Also, I wasn't quite sure about the three fundamental ways to make a member of $B_n$. Isn't $B_{n,2}$ = $B_n$? And aren't $B_{n,1}$ and $B_{n,3}$ subsets of $B_{n,2}$. Unless of course we assume that he i,j and k are different in $B_{n,2}$.
Thank you in advance for your answer, I am really curious about this!

Comment: Not sure comments are long enough to clarify, I'll see. Regarding subsets of $B$, consider $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1, 4, 11)$. We have $B_{3,1}=A=\{1,4,11\}$; then $B_{3,2}=\{1+4-11=-6,1+11-4=8, 4+11-1=14\}$; finally $B_{3,3}=\{2-11=-9, 2-4=-2, 8-11=-3,8-1=7,20-4=16,20-1=19\}$. The subsets are distinct, but the elements have some overlap: each element in $B_{3,2}$ can be made two ways, e.g., $11+(4-1)=4+(11-1)=14$; each element in $B_{3,1}$ can be made two ways, e.g., $11+(4-11)=1+(4-1)=4$.

Comment: To your first question, I'll definitely need to edit a better explanation into the answer; in fact, that's the part where I feel I was hand-waving at least a bit.

Comment: Ok, I fully understand that now, thank you.

That would be really nice of you, it is the only part left for me where I am not 100% convinced. Btw, I think the way you approached this is an amazing idea :)

Comment: OK, edited in some commentary about your first question. I'm now more convinced, but let me know what you think. Also, thanks for the kind comments! I don't think it's a particularly "novel" approach, just a way to keep track of all the cardinalities and still believe this will work for any finite set.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Eric. I think I have pretty good understanding of the steps for each of the individual $B_{i,j,k}$'s and I see how for each of these sets the number of positive elements is always higher than the number of negative elements. 
What i do not see yet is why isn't it possible for a change from $a_i$ to $a_i'$ where the set $B_{i',j,k}$ does not have any change in cardinality compared to $B_{i,j,k}$ that the positive elements of this new set however, do have more duplicates with the other $B_{x,y,z}$'s while the negative elemetns don't?

Comment: I have written a progamm, where i can calculate a set $A + A - A$ easily and I looked at several examples.
If $A = \{1, 3, 7, 20\}$ then the set $A + A - A$ contains 9 negative elements and 17 positive elements. If we change the 7 into an 8, we get the set $A' = \{1, 3, 8, 20\}$. Now $A' + A' - A'$ still contains 9 negative elements, but only 16 positive elements. So, with this step we only removed a positive element. Wouldn't that be a counterexample to the proof?

Comment: @MathwithFrank Well... darn. I'm going to have to look closely at the example and find out where the logic is off. I knew my logic wasn't watertight, but I didn't except that quick a collapse. Alas.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the issue: $\{1,3,7,20\}$ is *two* changes away from a maximal set; $\{1,3,8,20\}$ is only one change away. (The maximal set being $\{1,3,8,19\}$.) Backtracking will cause issues. There does seem to be something weird going on in the $\{1,3,8,19\} \to \{1,3,8,20\}$ transition, though; it creates an arithmetic progression of $4$ numbers, and causes $B$ to lose two positive and one negative value, not sure how that works. But the $\{1,3,8,20\} \to \{1,3,7,20\}$ transition involves *gaining back* a positive element.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that the different $B_{ijk}$'s have new overlaps or get rid of old overlaps. We are only looking at the overlaps in each $B_{ijk}$, but not with each other.  Working with these kind of overlaps will be pretty hard I think.

Comment: A counterexample has been posted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/a/447486/116247

Comment: @MartinR Well I think in a head-to-head with *Terry Tao* I'm going to lose. Thanks for the link. I just wish it were a constructive proof; my brain doesn't love the whole "yeah there's a counterexample, but it might need a billion-element set."